# MongoDB sort the result after limit

Tags: mongodb, sorting, limit

is there a way to sort the documents returned from limit?
example:

```
//returns 10 documents:
db.users.find()
.sort({last_online_timestamp:-1})
.limit(10) 

//returns 10 another documents
db.users.find()
.sort({last_online_timestamp:-1})
.limit(10)
.sort({messages_count:1});
```

what I want is to get 10 last logged in users and then sort them by messages count.

Comment: db.user.find().sort({last_online_timestamp:-1}).limit(10).pretty();

Comment: db.user.find().sort({last_online_timestamp: -1}).limit(10, callback);

Comment: try This ... ....

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar If you are suggesting a solution, you should post it as a full Answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @Alexander Tyuryaev : It is not possible to use sort() twice on a find() query; this has been addressed before, for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/43250870/174843 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/14425636/174843 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/8474353/174843. Instead you need to use an aggregation, as suggested by Jeff J.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an aggregate such as

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {"$sort": {"last_online_timestamp":1}},
    {"$limit": 10},
    {"$sort": {"messages_count": 1}}
])
```

This will go through stages where the the documents in the collection will be:

1. Sorted by the `last_online_timestamp` field in ascending order
2. Limited to 10 documents
3. Those 10 documents will be sorted by the `messages_count` field in ascending order

You may want to change `{"$sort": {"last_online_timestamp":1}` to `{"$sort": {"last_online_timestamp":-1}` depending on the actual values of `last_online_timestamp`

For more information on Mongo aggregation, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/.

Comment: I don't think `db.users.find().sort({last_online_timestamp:-1}).limit(10).sort({messages_count:1})` will work. As per docs, sort is always applied before limit irrespective of the order you write it in.

Comment: @demolisher You are correct - the syntax was accepted but the results were not what was expected.  I have updated the answer to include only the aggregate.  Thanks!

Comment: the syntax of "aggregate" is difficult to read. that one is better: db.users.aggregate().sort({"last_online_timestamp":1}).limit(10).sort({"messages_count": 1});